# A question about polynomials and imaginary roots

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots

What is the product of the imaginary roots of $x^7+px^2-q^2=0$? 
I did y=product of real roots, x=...imaginary roots, b=sum of the real roots, a=...imaginary roots.
And I did the system:
$yx=q^2\\
a+b=0\\
y+x+ab=0\\
xb+ya=p^2$

There is a best manner to do this question? Please.

Comment: You polynomial is of odd degrre, so  has at least one real root, say $r$, and therefore at most $6$ complex roots. Then, as the complex roots appears by pairs, you can write yor polynomal as $p(x):=(x-r)(x-(a_{1}+ib_{1}))(x-(a_{1}-ib_{1}))\cdots (x-(a_{6}-ib_{6}))$

Comment: @user123043 There might be three real roots instead of one.  Also there are at most three pairs.

Comment: What kind of numbers are $p$,$q$?

Comment: Yes, I mean c instead of a, sorry. So, I did wrong this system? Please, someone do this in the right way.

Comment: (1) Do you mean $c$ instead of $a$? (2) Even in this case, I can not realize how did you get the last two equations. (3) Using the [Descartes Sign Rule] (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DescartesSignRule.html), if $p≤0$ then we have exactly one real root[it should be positive]; and if $0<p$, then either we have exactly only one real root, or either 3 real roots[one of them should be positive, and the two others should be negative]